# "org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject"

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse a file in order to POST JSON data into a local platform which requires an access token. but I'm getting this error: `org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

I've tried many ways to fix it, but I didn't work.

Here's the code : 
 here's a part which i used it to convert my csv file into Json format

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
//import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

public class CSVtoJSON {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File input = new File("ArgosData_2020_05_24_22_21_59.csv");
            File output = new File("output.json");
            String access_token = "rxmqDZF0J1BCUIDm1Faw";

            CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
            CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

            // Read data from CSV file
            List<Object> readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);

            // Write JSON formated data to stdout
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
```

And then I tried to post the data, in this part i got the error message :

```
 try {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                //Use JSONObject for simple JSON and JSONArray for array of JSON.
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(
                        new FileReader(output.getAbsolutePath()));//path to the JSON file.
                System.out.println(data.toJSONString());

                String paramValue = "param\\with\\backslash";
                String yourURLStr = "http://host.com?param=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8");

                URL url2 = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer" + access_token);

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8");
                outStreamWriter.write(data.toJSONString());
                outStreamWriter.flush();
                outStreamWriter.close();
                outStream.close();
                String response = null;

                System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

                DataInputStream input1 = null;
                input1 = new DataInputStream (conn.getInputStream());
                while (null != ((response = input1.readLine()))) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    input1.close ();
                }
            } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

If anybody who has a clue how to do so, I'm new to programming and I'd be grateful to get some help.

Comment: Let me get this clear, you’re writing a list to a json, not a JsonObject, and are now trying to cast that list (JsonArray) to a JsonObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a list of objects and try to read a single object.

If you look at the file, you probably see something like this:
`[{"name": "Object1", value="1"}, {"name": "Object2"}, {"name": Object3"}]`.

With `JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(...` you're trying to read a single JSON object, e.g. `{"name":"i'm a single object' "value"="42"}`.
To fix the imminent problem, use `JSONArray data` instead of `JSONObject` like the message suggests.

I'm not familiar with `org.json.simple` and couldn't see to find this specific library, so I currently cannot suggest any further code snippets to try.

Comment: I agree with you, actually I have a list of objects so I think maybe that's the problem, I'll try to use JSONArray instead and see if it can solve it.